I am remoting into Ubuntu server via iPad/rdp, would like to send app output to server video ports
RDP allows me to login to Ubuntu from a remote iPad, I would like to send out info on the Ubuntu video ports. For example I would like to send firefox www.somewebsite.com to he Ubuntu server video like DISPLAY=ubuntu_ip_address:0. This is not allowed, app reports display cannot be opened. Is there a way to attach an app like Firefox to the Ubuntu servers HDMI ports logging into the server via RDP. There is no keyboard or mouse attached to the Ubuntu server. So I need to use RDP or VNC, but I want to display dynamic web pages out the unused video ports on the Ubuntu server. I will not be able to login to the Ubuntu server so screen sharing is not a viable option. Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Trying to use the HDMI ports like Kiosk mode of an iPad.


Please edit the question and include the Ubuntu version info and a complete list of what you have tried and the results.
